# Attempt to read property "email" on int - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a Work model where one of its attributes is the requestor, I am trying to obtain the requestor´s data (I can already obtain the primary key).

In this way I call the view:

```
    $obras = Obra::all();
    return view("obra.index", compact("obras"));
```

The view:

```
    @forelse ($obras as $i)
        <li>{{ $i->requestor_id->email }}</li>
    @empty
```

The relationship in the work model:

```
    public function requestor_id(){
    
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
```

Tables:

Users(applicants) have: id, name, email, password etc.

Work have: id, user_id, start_date etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I had the relations wrong, I had to use `hasOne` in the requester model (in the end I used `hasMany` because someone can create more than one work) and in the work model use `belongsTo`.

**IMPORTANT** note: the name of the function in the model cannot be the same as the name of a field in your table. Also in my case the column names do not follow the laravel/eloquent nomenclature so another parameter is added to `belongsTo` with the field name.

Work model:

```
public function solicitante(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "requestor_id");
}
```

Requestor model:

```
 public function obra(){
   return $this->hasMany(Obra::class, "requestor_id");
}
```

And how to obtain requester data: `$obra->solicitante->email`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the name of the relation. You can try to renaming it to requestor. Laravel has some internal behavior runing on underscore. It might return only the id.

```
public function requestor()
{    
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

Comment: That way I get an error, it seems that instead of looking for the id of the applicant in the work, it is looking for the id of the work in the applicant table.

Comment: Can you share the list of fields of the 2 tables? If you don't follow the naming convention, Laravel would not establish the relationship properly

Answer (score 0):

import `use App\Models\Obra;` in the Controller.

```
use App\Models\Obra;

$obras = Obra::all();
return view("obra.index", compact("obras"));
```

Comment: Hello, you should explain a bit what your code is doing, and how it helps on OP's question. So it can be useful very fast for the next readers.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake but now I did it

Answer (score 0):

Returned function must be same table name exm:

```
public function obra(){
   return $this->hasMany(Obra::class, "requestor_id");
}
```

table name must be obra